# JS/jQ make a URL builder function without duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I should say, I just want to solve this as logic, not my real code is jQuery or JavaScript, because I learning `reactjs` I trying to solve this logic with jQ or JS then do it in React. So I don't want a solution like `$.param` and also don't want to replace last `&` with something, I looking for to make a URL Builder function, What I trying to do is add URL parameter (Query String) What I tried so far is:

```js
let obj = {}
let array = []
let url = 'http://www.example.com/foo';

function buildUrl(base, key, value) {
  var sep = (base.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&' : '?';
  return base + sep + key + '=' + value;
}

$('#btn1').click(function() {
  obj = {
    name: 'province',
    value: 11
  }
  array.push(obj)
  console.log('param 1 added!')
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
  obj = {
    name: 'city',
    value: 2
  }
  array.push(obj)
  console.log('param 2 added!')
});

$('#build').click(function() {
  $.each(array, function(i, v) {
    url = buildUrl(url, v.name, v.value);
  });
  console.log(url)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">1. Click this</button>
<kbd>-></kbd>
<button id="btn2">2. Then click this</button>
<kbd>=</kbd>
<button id="build">Make URL</button>
```

Somehow, it add province twice, I don't how to make this function to avoid duplicate parameters, any idea?

*side note: I have many btn to build parameter, so I can't detect value each time!*

Comment: It is all [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)  and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)  and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
let url = new URL('http://www.example.com/foo');
let params = url.searchParams;

document.getElementById("buts").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('add')) {
    params.set(tgt.id, tgt.getAttribute('data-value'));
    console.log('param ' + tgt.id + ' added!', params.toString())
  }
});
document.getElementById("build").addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(url));
```

```html
<div id="buts">
  <button class="add" id="province" data-value="11">1. Click this</button>
  <kbd>-></kbd>
  <button class="add" id="city" data-value="2">2. Then click this</button>
  <kbd>=</kbd>
  <button id="build">Make URL</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay maybe this working, but this is not answer to my question, I want to use `object` and also need to use a function!, also there is no explanation, I trying to see what you done, and turn it to what I want!, feel free to give me another down vote ;)

Comment: Who said I voted down? What I gave you is a vanilla is solution that is much more suited to add to react than a jq one

Comment: No I said, you can add another down vote, already has 2! , you solution is clear and good, but I want to use object and funciton, not data-value..